# How to set independent DL rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, distribution-list

I'm trying to set rules for a Distribution List in Outlook O365 so that they are independent on my account as the person who created them.
I already tried to create some from my usual name.surname@company.com account and marked them "`on server`". I now need to know whether they remain even if my AD account is disabled/removed or would this have to be set in o365/exchange management console?

Comment: Your Outlook email account is likely independent of your AD account.  However, distribution lists are an Exchange thing and not an account thing.  What do you mean '...they are independent on my account...'  If your 'dist list' is just a rule to forward emails around then your good.  You can log on to any computer and use a browser to access your O365 Outlook and check your mail/rules/etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create rules in Outlook for your account, after disabling and enabling this account in AD, the rules still locate there.

If you remove your account in AD, when you try to access this mailbox in Outlook/OWA, there will be only an old data file and the old rules are not available any more, or you couldn't access them because of "**Work Offline**".

Therefore, if you want to remove your account in AD due to some reasons, and you still need keep the rules for it, mail flow rule is more suitable(Create a rule to deal your emails. For example, if the sender is your account, redirect/delete emails.).